# Create gif without losing the white color

Tags: gif, gimp, angular-ng-if

I realize when creating gifs, the quality of the outcome suffers. Is there a way to retain the "whiteness" of the background? The result now has a yellowish tone and it stands out when implementing in a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIFs are color-indexed and limited to 256 colors per image(*). When exporting a full-RGB image to GIF, Gimp does an implicit conversion to color-indexed and tries to find a best fit. If you want white the best way is to explicitly do the color indexing (`Image>Mode>Indexed`) and then edit the colormap (`Layers>Dockable dialog>Colormap`), find the color of the background and change it to white.  You can also specify a palette when doing the color indexing, if this palette contains a white color then it will be used.

Otherwise, if you are doing still images, you may want to switch to the PNG format...

(*) that is, in the single image, or in all layers/frames combined. If you are using animations. More recent variant of the GIF format allow 256 colors per frame, when doing animations, but GIMP doesn't support these.